# Why does FaceAlpha affect ZData of different object?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

working with matlab 2015a in linux.
trying this code  (with the slice grid ,x and y in the mat file attached)
[FaveAlpha.mat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/35130/FaceAlpha.mat)

```
load('FaceAlpha.mat'); % Loading SliceGrid and X,Y parametrs
hold on; xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), zlabel('Z'); axis equal;
axis image; 
plot(SliceGrid.x(X),SliceGrid.y(Y),'blue.');hold on;
h=[-8 -0.5 0.5 1]
v=[7 4 4 7];
fill_2=fill(h,v,'blue'); % Creating blue object
x=[0 -0.5 0.5 1]
y=[9 4 4 9];
fill_1=fill(x,y,'red');% Creating red object
t=[-2 -0.5 0.5 2];
z=[9 2 2 0];
fill_3=fill(t,z,'yellow'); % Creating yellow object
set(fill_1,'FaceAlpha',0.5); % After this line everthing is ok.
set(fill_2, 'ZData', repmat(10, size(get(fill_2, 'XData')))); %  After this line the outside blue plot is damaged  - as you can see in the above figure
%%%%%%%%%%%% if we omit the  line ->  set(fill_1,'FaceAlpha',0.5);
%%%%%%%%%%%% and leave the code with the ZData property, the outside blue plot doesn't damaged.  
%%%%%%%%%%%% if we omit the  line ->  set(fill_2, 'ZData', repmat(10, size(get(fill_2, 'XData'))));
%%%%%%%%%%%% and leave the code with the FaceAlpha property, the outside blue plot doesn't damaged.
```

why and how does face alpha affect other object with ZData? and why are they doesn't work together? what is wrong? Thank you!!

before:
[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: It's an issue with the renderer. Would you be fine with the vector renderer painters? -> `set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')`. And apart from that, what do you want to do with the Z-Data in your 2D-plot? Can you post a screenshot of how it looks and what you want to have changed?

Comment: HI @thewaywewalk  added the screen shotss

Comment: okay, so it looks the same like on my machine, what particulary makes me wonder, is that the blue patch comes in front. That is not desired, is it? And what about the `painters` approach, have you tried it?

Comment: So it seems that line of code after ZData fix the problem- `set(gca,'SortMethod','childorder')`

Comment: this is an interesting property I never used before. You should post it as answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I will, tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems that if we will check the code of after this line of code:

```
set(fill_1,'FaceAlpha',0.5);
a=get(gca,'SortMethod')
```

We will get a=childorder, that means that the appearance of every object is by the child order of gca of the figure (And this is by the way is the default)
After the line of code of ZData, that order is changed by Matlab, its changing to depth, so if you will re-use the function :

```
a=get(gca,'SortMethod')
```

a=depth now.

So if you want to fix the problem just use this code:

```
set(gca,'SortMethod','childorder')
```

And - We have a winner! :)